# Una imagen se rompe cuando conecto a la libreria de boostrap

Tags: html, css

Imagen con la librería de Bootstrap conectada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen sin la librería de Bootstrap conectada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola a todos, estuve desarrollando una página y conecté un carrusel de Bootstrap con unos mapas en vez de imágenes. Estaba todo bien, hasta que me dí cuenta de que la navbar estaba rota. Por lo que pasé 1 hora viendo que era lo que la rompía hasta que desactivé la conexión a Bootstrap desde el link.
Luego de eso, la navbar volvía a la normalidad. Pero no entiendo que sería lo que la estaría rompiendo. Pasó el código css, pero mi presentimiento es que alguna clase esté coincidiendo con Bootstrap o algo así. Porque deshabilité el código css y sigue igual.  Si alguien me ayuda, se lo agradezco mucho.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Dernocua | Ubicación</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Img/Dernocua.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header> 
        <div class="navbar"> <!-- Menú de Nav -->
            <a href="../index.html" class="Logo"><img src="../Img/Solo letras.png" alt="Nombre Dernocua"></a>
            <nav> 
                <ul class="Links">
                    <li><a href="../index.html" class="active">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./Contacto.html" class="df contacto">Contacto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./Nosotros.html" class="df">Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./Productos.html" class="df">Productos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./Ubicación.html" class="df">Ubicación</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <main>
        <div class="ContenedorTitulo">
            <h1 class="titulo noIndex" >Ubicación</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="UbicacionesPresentación">
            <h2>Dernocua se encuentra en dos ubicaciones diferentes</h2>
            <p>A continuación encontraras un mapa con la ubicación actual de Dernocua</p>
        </div>
    </main>


    <section>
        <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide w-75 mx-auto bg-black carouseldiv">
            <div class="carousel-indicators">
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>  
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m23!1m12!1m3!1d24038.444644175037!2d-71.30577655391069!3d-41.13876998751071!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m8!3e0!4m0!4m5!1s0x961a7b1520c860e5%3A0x8210ae97cb7b9a65!2sSan%20Carlos%20de%20Bariloche%2C%20R%C3%ADo%20Negro!3m2!1d-41.1334722!2d-71.3102778!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sar!4v1676383078845!5m2!1sen!2sar" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade" class="d-block w-100"></iframe>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5 class="TextCarousel">Bariloche - No hay lugar físico</h5>
                    <p class="TextCarousel">Dernocua se encuentra haciendo entregas en Bariloche, ya que no cuenta con un lugar físico. Si quieres organizar una entrega, <a href="./Contacto.html">comunícate con nosotros</a> o chatea con nosotros por nuestras redes sociales</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m23!1m12!1m3!1d94933.66049396094!2d-71.6042609841753!3d-41.964274715403356!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m8!3e6!4m0!4m5!1s0x961bbfcfd1839071%3A0x1b20d1fe9b77ae58!2sGral.%20Roca%2C%20El%20Bols%C3%B3n%2C%20R%C3%ADo%20Negro!3m2!1d-41.964296!2d-71.5342211!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sar!4v1676382257676!5m2!1sen!2sar" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade" class="d-block w-100"></iframe> 
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5 class="TextCarousel">El Bolsón - Feria regional</h5>
                    <p class="TextCarousel">Dernocua se encuentra con un lugar físico en la feria regional de el Bolsón. Acá podrás apreciar algunos de nuestros productos, los dias habíles de feria</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </section> 
    
    <footer>
        <div class="footer-content">
            <img src="../Img/Dernocua logo y nombre.png" alt="Logo de Dernocua" class="LogoFooter">
            <ul class="socials">
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100084937357541" target="_blank" class="Face"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/dernocua/?fbclid=IwAR2qWeldLcAL_g2Lmc_AizQINRMRyN1Q34er-c5KJj5J0bY8YRoaZrIyLvI" target="_blank" class="Ig"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <p>copyright &copy;2023. Creado por <span><a href="https://github.com/Nehuen627" target="_blank">Nehuen</a></span></p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

```
/* Ubicación */
.UbicacionesPresentación h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin: 0% auto 4% auto;
}
.UbicacionesPresentación p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.carouseldiv {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 0.5%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
}
.TextCarousel {
    color: black;
}
.TextCarousel a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c800ff;
}
```

Comment: Debes describir el problema y además agregar un [MRE] valido, y mucha énfasis en "mínimo" que tu problema está acotado solo en el menú

Comment: Si trabajaras con css puro en lugar de bootstrap, no pasaran esas cosas. Es tipico de los frameworks que al agregarlos provoquen resultados indeseados en lo que ya tenias hecho

Answer (score 0):

Perdón por las molestias, al parecer la class="navbar" creaba algo que me descontrolaba todo. Ya lo pude solucionar
Estuve buscando por un rato largo, sacando partes del codigo y volviendo a ponerlas, hasta que descubrí que cuando conectaba a boostrap se rompía todo. Por lo que estaba seguro que era el framework.
Desde ahí pase un rato buscando que era lo que hacía interferencia con el framework; ya desde un principio pensaba que era un class.
Desde html, me autocompletaba pero ninguna clase de las que tenía parecía hacer ruido. Por lo que me fuí a w3school, y busqué en el listado de clases de boostrap, y encontré que la clase navbar, creaba algo, no puse a fijar bien porque no era mi objetivo. Por lo que procedí a agregarle a mi class="navbar" navbarDernocua y se arregló!
Dejo el procedimiento por si a alguien le sirve la información

Comment: Lo mejor es que borres la pregunta

Comment: Hola Franco, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, sería bueno que intentaras  ubicar el cambio que solucionó tu problema, publicarlo como respuesta y marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Esas cosas pasan por usar los "benditos" frameworks :(